# Generate localized URL for a translated page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localization, c1-cms

According to [How localization works](http://docs.composite.net/HTML/C1-Localization/How-localization-works) I can translate pages and give them a different URL for every language.

Example from the tutorial:

- `http://butterflysite.co.uk/en-GB/Home/contact/Newoffice.aspx` (english)
- `http://vlindersite.nl/nl-NL/thuis/contact/NieuwKantoor.aspx` (dutch)

My question is now: Assuming I know which language I am currently in, how do I find out what the URL title for my page is in C#?

What is the best way to use the C1 API to create the correct link to the page in the current language?

Comment: How is that related? This is a Composite C1 question.

Comment: Doh! Never mind. It's Monday and I haven't had my coffe yet. Sorry. I'll remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant No1

```
    public string GetPageUrl(Guid pageId, CultureInfo locale)
    {
        using(var conn = new DataConnection(PublicationScope.Published, locale))
        {
            var pageNode = new SitemapNavigator(conn).GetPageNodeById(pageId);
            return pageNode != null ? pageNode.Url : null;
        }
    }
```

Variant No2

```
    public string GetPageUrl(Guid pageId, CultureInfo locale)
    {
        var pageUrlData = new PageUrlData(pageId, PublicationScope.Published, locale);
        return PageUrls.BuildUrl(pageUrlData, UrlKind.Public, new UrlSpace());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

atticae, have a look to the CurrentPageNode - @CurrentPageNode.MenuTitle

Comment: The current page node is not the one I want to link to though. And the Menutitle of a PageNode only helps me if I it is not translated as well.

Comment: atticae, please provide more details, we will help you